# Ubuntu - Gnome: Chrome 107 breaks the position of the close button in classic theme appearance

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, themes

Chrome 107 on Linux breaks the position of the close button in classic theme appearance. The window close button is forced to the right. It was working in Chrome 106.

[image]

Is there a way to force the position of the close button in the Ubuntu Gnome window theme?

This is Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.28-3.36 and yaru-theme-gnome-shell                  20.04.11.1.

Comment: I can confirm I am seeing this issue as well on much older 18.04 and Chrome 107.  Switching to the GTK theme fixed it.

Comment: Upstream bug is here - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370444